# I keep getting this error "multiple root tags" and "unexpected end of file"

Tags: android, android-manifest

I keep getting this error "multiple root tags" and "unexpected end of file"
I'm following a book about Android Studio and its telling to write this code. (Down)I've followed what the book said and I just don't get it. Beginning of 1st line bolded and end of 2nd line bolded

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.congruency.bookguide">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/cool"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        **Manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**
        package="com.example.activitydemo"
        android:versionCode="1"
        **android:versionName="1.0"**
```

Comment: Are you sure this is only one entire file? This is not valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have anything after your closing `</manifest>` tag? That is the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.activitydemo"
    android:versionCode="1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/cool"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: oh...opps... Thanks! but i know have an error saying that Element Manifest is not closed...